# Not finding python3 when installing pycairo

Tags: python, python-3.x, cairo, pycairo

I'm trying to install pycairo. I downloaded the pycairo-1.10.0 folder and am trying to follow instructions. I have python3.5 installed in the location shown at the bottom of the screen shot [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62wfr.png), but when running config, it doesn't find it.

I'm running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

**Install Procedure**

```
$ ./waf --help    

$ ./waf configure  ( use --prefix and --libdir if necessary, --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64  for Fedora 64-bit)

$ ./waf build
$ ./waf install
```

**Use**

```
$ python3 ./waf ...
if you have python2 and python3 installed, and the default is python 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use pip? In pip [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/installing/index.html#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel) may be solution to your problem.

On Linux, Mac OS X:

```
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
python3.5 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.5
```

On Windows:

```
py -2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
py -2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
py -3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
py -3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Pycairo uses an ancient version of the `waf` build tool.
You will need to patch the `waflib/Build.py` file in pycairo to make it work with Python 3.5.

Below is the fix as [applied](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/graphics/py3-cairo/files/pycairo-1.10.0-waf-py3_5.patch?revision=401900&view=markup) to the FreeBSD ports tree:

```
--- a/waflib/Build.py
+++ b/waflib/Build.py
@@ -151,6 +151,7 @@ class BuildContext(Context.Context):
                                f.close()
                self.init_dirs()
        def store(self):
+               return
                data={}
                for x in SAVED_ATTRS:
                        data[x]=getattr(self,x)
```